# Fill consecutive NaNs with cumsum, to increment by one on each consecutive NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, cumulative-sum

Given a dataframe with lots of missing value in a certain inverval, my desired output dataframe should have all consecutive `NaN` filled with a `cumsum` starting from the first valid value, and adding `1` for each `NaN`.

Given:

```
shop_id calendar_date quantity
0       2018-12-12      1  
1       2018-12-13      NaN    
2       2018-12-14      NaN    
3       2018-12-15      NaN
4       2018-12-16      1
5       2018-12-17      NaN
```

Desired output:

```
shop_id calendar_date quantity 
0       2018-12-12      1    
1       2018-12-13      2    
2       2018-12-14      3    
3       2018-12-15      4
4       2018-12-16      1
5       2018-12-17      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
g = (~df.quantity.isnull()).cumsum()
df['quantity'] = df.fillna(1).groupby(g).quantity.cumsum()

      shop_id calendar_date  quantity
0        0    2018-12-12       1.0
1        1    2018-12-13       2.0
2        2    2018-12-14       3.0
3        3    2018-12-15       4.0
4        4    2018-12-16       1.0
5        5    2018-12-17       2.0
```

**Details**

Use [`.isnull()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.isnull.html) to check where `quantity` has valid values, and take the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) of the boolean Series:

```
g = (~df.quantity.isnull()).cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
```

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
so that when you group by `g` and take the [`cusmum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) the values will increase starting from whatever the value is:

```
df.fillna(1).groupby(g).quantity.cumsum()
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
```

Comment: it can be done with a for loop, but this answer is more elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach ?

**data**

```
   shop_id calender_date  quantity
0        0    2018-12-12       1.0
1        1    2018-12-13       NaN
2        2    2018-12-14       NaN
3        3    2018-12-15       NaN
4        4    2018-12-16       1.0
5        5    2018-12-17       NaN
6        6    2018-12-18       NaN
7        7    2018-12-17       NaN
```

using **np.where**

```
where = np.where(data['quantity'] >= 1)

r = []
for i in range(len(where[0])):
    try:
        r.extend(np.arange(1,where[0][i+1] - where[0][i]+1))
    except:
        r.extend(np.arange(1,len(data)-where[0][i]+1))

data['quantity'] = r
```

print(data)

```
   shop_id calender_date  quantity
0        0    2018-12-12         1
1        1    2018-12-13         2
2        2    2018-12-14         3
3        3    2018-12-15         4
4        4    2018-12-16         1
5        5    2018-12-17         2
6        6    2018-12-18         3
7        7    2018-12-17         4
```